# Foreign key in same table, unable to get right query

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I've got a very simple table that looks something like this. 
Iet's call the table 'family' the columns are ID, name, age and parent so:

```
ID    Name      Age     Parent
------------------------------
1     Bob        50      NULL
2     Matt       20        1  
3     Rick       18        1
```

ID is the primary key and Parent is a foreign key referencing ID
What I'm trying to do is to list every parents ID and name.
My current query looks like this:

```
Select ID, Name
from family
where ID = Parent;
```

But this is comes up with no results. How is my query incorrect? Shouldn't it show all records for all the parent ID's found? Thanks!
The result that I am looking for would look like this:

```
ID    Name    
--------------
1     Bob
```

And if the table was larger and had multiple parents, they would of course be listed in the result as well.

Comment: You cannot be your own parent, so that query will never return anything.  You also cannot simply check for `Parent Is Null` because technically everyone has a parent.  Are you looking for everyone that IS a parent?

Comment: How can `ID = parent` ever be true? Can a person be their own parent? You need to join the table with itself, and use `t1.ID = t2.Parent` as the joining condition.

Comment: @DaveJohnson In his table Bob doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @Barmar Time travel!

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but it will not be a reliable query to say "he has no Parent listed, therefore he is a parent"

Comment: @DaveJohnson Yeah, I misunderstood the reason he selected Bob in the desired results. I thought he wanted everyone who has no parents. That's the problem with such a limited sample in the example.

Comment: Despite my earlier joke, it is worth noting (since we don't know the use of this table): if a person can be their own parent and you enforce the foreign key with a constraint, you will probably not be able to delete that person without setting their parent field to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query attempt does not compare rows against each other, this is (posssibly) the simplest:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM family
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Parent FROM family)
;
```

This alternative MIGHT be faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.Name
FROM family AS p
INNER JOIN family AS c ON p.ID = c.Parent
;
```

Comment: In my experience, MySQL generally optimizes the second better.

Comment: @Barmar The second would be my bet as well; I've generally avoided subqueries like the first for the last ten years, but sometimes it seems they are easier for others to understand.

Comment: Yeah... agreed with @Uueerdo

Comment: Thank you, the first query worked perfectly. I tried a solution like that as well, but forgot to use 'IN'. So my major mistake was that I tried to compare rows against each other but that was not possible the way I attempted it?
I picked the first solution because it is slightly more readable to me and seems easier in my head.

Comment: @MaxVZ Yes, the problem with your query was there was no way to compare rows against each other; that is generally not possible without a JOIN of some sort. The first query isn't really comparing rows directly, it is getting rows that have IDs in a calculated set; that set happening to be the set of values found in the Parent field of the same table. The second query I provided may be faster because MySQL will be more likely able to take advantage of indexes on the ID and Parent fields (if present); but significant performance differences may no become obvious unless(until?) the table grows.